# required high performance of MapState for application data snapshot

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

As we have a streaming application for doing trade clearing, and we need to cache all the accounts in the memory and checkpoint to snapshot regular to avoid data lost.

The cache needs to be in sync with the snapshot and provide intensive read/write operations.

We have tried with the following codes and found the performance is not so good.

```java
MapState<KEY, VALUE> orderState = runtimeContext.getMapState(new 
MapStateDescriptor(name, TypeInformation.of(keyType), TypeInformation.of(valueType)));

MapStateStorage<KEY, VALUE> mapStateStorage = new MapStateStorage<>(orderState);
```

we cache the business objects in our own Map, and on the commit phase, we get the modified ones and put to the *mapStateStorage*

with the configuration

```
rocksdb.filepath=s3://test-flink/${ENV_NAME}/rocksdb
```

From the codes of *RocksDBMapState*, the put will go to rocksdb and the write will go to rocksdb too with penalty on the serialization and deserialization.

Any best practice that already existed for such kind of high r/w rates?

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

I'm curious to know why you have chosen the RocksDB state backend, as it sounds like everything fits in memory and you are using Flink state only for fault tolerance. If that's the case, have you explored using the FsStateBackend? It has much better throughput and average latency (though its worst-case latency is affected by the need for GC). This would avoid the serde overhead, and since everything would simply be objects on the heap, you could also then explore not bothering with your cache and thereby avoid the copy you are currently doing.

In the future you might also want to consider the [Spillable Heap Keyed State Backend](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/FLINK/FLIP-50%3A+Spill-able+Heap+Keyed+State+Backend).

Comment: *RocksDB* provides the incremental checkpoint that's why we choose instead of FsStateBackend. Actually we are finding a backend that can support heap storage for quick retrieval and high-performance snapshot to avoid data lost.